# sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?

Tags: macos, permission, sudo, root

I was trying to remove some folders (python) via `sudo rm` in Terminal and got this message:

```
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
```

I already tried to verify/repair disk permissions (only shows 1 error, apple's remote agent), but that didn't help.

```
$ sudo
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?

$ type sudo
sudo is hashed (/usr/local/bin/sudo)

$ ls -@@eil /usr/bin/sudo
2215747 -r-s--x--x  1 root  wheel  164560 Sep 10  2014 /usr/bin/sudo

$ md5 /usr/bin/sudo
md5: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied
```

OS X 10.10.4

Comment: Please add within your original question (OQ) which version of MacOS X you had this error message.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use this `/usr/local/bin/sudo`?↵ Do you know its origin?↵Did you install it?

Comment: i don't know where it came from, maybe homebrew, but I deleted it, now os x is using the right one, thank you for helping!

Comment: It's modification date might have helped you. This will be for another question next time you hit a binary not being the one you think.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, you have a `sudo` installed in `/usr/local/bin` (see the output of `type`). Did you install something with homebrew or another package manager?

To fix, run

```
/usr/bin/sudo mv /usr/local/bin/sudo /usr/local/bin/sudo-strange
```

or (if you want to get rid of it completely)

```
/usr/bin/sudo rm /usr/local/bin/sudo
```

Comment: thank you, yes, i did some installing with homebrew (python etc), i did what you wrote, but how do i tell os x now to use /usr/bin/sudo as default? @patrix

Comment: Once you rename/remove the `sudo` in `/usr/local/bin`, things should be back to normal. You can also run `hash -r` to make the shell forget about the location of `sudo`.

Comment: Feel free to borrow the useful part of my answer (which wasn't complete) to make a complete one of yours. I'll remove my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your command `/usr/bin/sudo` isn't running with the correct access modes
or you are not running the `sudo` you think.

To help you identify the exact nature of what is wrong, run the following commands in a `Terminal`:

```
type sudo
```

(to check you are using the true `sudo` without any intervening subshell)

```
ls -@eil /usr/bin/sudo
```

(to check modes, owner, group, and extended access list of the correct binary)

```
/usr/bin/sudo md5 /usr/bin/sudo
```

(to check no one tampered with your binary `sudo`).

Comment: edited again, didn't use *type sudo*, seems like I'm using a wrong sudo (should be in another folder, right?) @daniel

Comment: Right! (+ garbage for the robot)